# Kafka commits transaction after LeaveGroup due to max.poll.interval.ms is exceeded

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using transaction in kafka. I have provided my consumer container with a `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` which consist of `JpaTransactionManager` and `KafkaTransactionManager`.

I am trying to learn how transactions are affected when a consumer is stuck and therefore send `LeaveGroup` and disables heartbeat thread.

I have set `max.poll.interval.ms` to 10 seconds.

I have not changed `session.timeout.ms`. It is 10 seconds per default.

I have two applications with one consumer each. Both consumers are transactional. Consumer A is rigged to process for 30 seconds and Consumer B process it within 1 second. Both consumers read from the same topic, which as 3 partitions.

1. Send a record to Kafka
2. Consumer A receives the record.
3. Consumer A starts to process the record.
4. Consumer A processing time exceed `max.poll.interval.ms`
5. Consumer A send LeaveGroup and heartbeat stops.
6. Kafka rebalances. All partitions are now assigned to Consumer B.
7. Consumer B receives the same record and process it.
8. Consumer B commits the transaction.
9. Consumer A has now finished processing(30 seconds).
10. Consumer A commits the transaction.
11. Kafka rebalances. Partitions are reassigned to both consumers.

The transaction is processed and committed twice. Both consumers should be idempotent to ensure processing the same record have no consequences.

My hypothesis was that Consumer A would throw an exception due to LeaveGroup and stopping the heartbeat. This is however not the case. I have tested this with unique transaction IDs and transaction ID being identical in both applications - same result.

Why does Consumer A commit the transaction after LeaveGroup has been sent?

I am not entirely sure if this is a bug. I have however submitted this odd behaviour or bug to [Apache Kafka](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7153)

**Log for Consumer A**

```
2018-07-11 11:59:22.365 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Received: 1 records
2018-07-11 11:59:22.366 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2018-07-11 11:59:22.366 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=transactionId420] Transition from state READY to IN_TRANSACTION
2018-07-11 11:59:22.366 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Created Kafka transaction on producer [brave.kafka.clients.TracingProducer@631071b0]
2018-07-11 11:59:22.366 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2018-07-11 11:59:22.366 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2018-07-11 11:59:22.366 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2018-07-11 11:59:22.367 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@4eef56f0]
2018-07-11 11:59:22.427 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] l.a.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=[data], headers={kafka_offset=[34], kafka_consumer=brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer@1484643f, kafka_timestampType=[CREATE_TIME], kafka_receivedMessageKey=[null], kafka_receivedPartitionId=[1], kafka_receivedTopic=[trans-topic], kafka_receivedTimestamp=[1531299912221], kafka_batchConvertedHeaders=[{X-B3-SpanId=[B@1e664339, X-B3-ParentSpanId=[B@73f2c38a, X-B3-Sampled=[B@5f0ca155, X-B3-TraceId=[B@68ac877c}]}]]

...
2018-07-11 11:59:30.503 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [hread | mygrp42] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygrp42] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2018-07-11 11:59:30.608 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [hread | mygrp42] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygrp42] Received successful Heartbeat response
2018-07-11 11:59:32.256 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [hread | mygrp42] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygrp42] Sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2018-07-11 11:59:32.256 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [hread | mygrp42] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygrp42] Disabling heartbeat thread
2018-07-11 11:59:37.458 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Sending offsets to transaction: {trans-topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=408, metadata=''}}
2018-07-11 11:59:37.465 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=transactionId420] Begin adding offsets {trans-topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=408, metadata=''}} for consumer group mygrp42 to transaction
2018-07-11 11:59:37.465 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=transactionId420] Enqueuing transactional request (type=AddOffsetsToTxnRequest, transactionalId=transactionId420, producerId=0, producerEpoch=64, consumerGroupId=mygrp42)
2018-07-11 11:59:37.465 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=transactionId420] Sending transactional request (type=AddOffsetsToTxnRequest, transactionalId=transactionId420, producerId=0, producerEpoch=64, consumerGroupId=mygrp42) to node localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
2018-07-11 11:59:37.467 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=transactionId420] Successfully added partition for consumer group mygrp42 to transaction
2018-07-11 11:59:37.467 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=transactionId420] Sending transactional request (type=TxnOffsetCommitRequest, transactionalId=transactionId420, producerId=0, producerEpoch=64, consumerGroupId=mygrp42, offsets={trans-topic-0=CommittedOffset(offset=408, metadata='')}) to node localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
2018-07-11 11:59:37.469 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46299 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=transactionId420] Successfully added offsets {trans-topic-0=CommittedOffset(offset=408, metadata='')} from consumer group mygrp42 to transaction.
```

**Log for Consumer B**

```
2018-07-11 11:59:33.777 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Received: 1 records
2018-07-11 11:59:33.777 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2018-07-11 11:59:33.777 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-2, transactionalId=transactionId421] Transition from state READY to IN_TRANSACTION
2018-07-11 11:59:33.777 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Created Kafka transaction on producer [brave.kafka.clients.TracingProducer@30b6dff4]
2018-07-11 11:59:33.778 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2018-07-11 11:59:33.778 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2018-07-11 11:59:33.778 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2018-07-11 11:59:33.778 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@2b0eff5d]
2018-07-11 11:59:33.778 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] l.a.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=[data], headers={kafka_offset=[407], kafka_consumer=brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer@103b53ce, kafka_timestampType=[CREATE_TIME], kafka_receivedMessageKey=[null], kafka_receivedPartitionId=[0], kafka_receivedTopic=[trans-topic], kafka_receivedTimestamp=[1531299562360], kafka_batchConvertedHeaders=[{X-B3-SpanId=[B@38658f41, X-B3-ParentSpanId=[B@2faeb13a, X-B3-Sampled=[B@29e18244, X-B3-TraceId=[B@75496432}]}]]
2018-07-11 11:59:33.778 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Sending offsets to transaction: {trans-topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=408, metadata=''}}
2018-07-11 11:59:33.778 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-2, transactionalId=transactionId421] Begin adding offsets {trans-topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=408, metadata=''}} for consumer group mygrp42 to transaction
2018-07-11 11:59:33.778 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-2, transactionalId=transactionId421] Enqueuing transactional request (type=AddOffsetsToTxnRequest, transactionalId=transactionId421, producerId=1, producerEpoch=11, consumerGroupId=mygrp42)
2018-07-11 11:59:33.779 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ad | producer-2] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-2, transactionalId=transactionId421] Sending transactional request (type=AddOffsetsToTxnRequest, transactionalId=transactionId421, producerId=1, producerEpoch=11, consumerGroupId=mygrp42) to node localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
2018-07-11 11:59:33.780 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ad | producer-2] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-2, transactionalId=transactionId421] Successfully added partition for consumer group mygrp42 to transaction
2018-07-11 11:59:33.780 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ad | producer-2] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-2, transactionalId=transactionId421] Sending transactional request (type=TxnOffsetCommitRequest, transactionalId=transactionId421, producerId=1, producerEpoch=11, consumerGroupId=mygrp42, offsets={trans-topic-0=CommittedOffset(offset=408, metadata='')}) to node localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
2018-07-11 11:59:33.781 DEBUG [kafka-transaction-microservice-example,,,] 46288 --- [ad | producer-2] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-2, transactionalId=transactionId421] Successfully added offsets {trans-topic-0=CommittedOffset(offset=408, metadata='')} from consumer group mygrp42 to transaction.
```

Comment: YIKES! I am seeing the same behavior; looks like a bug in Kafka to me; I would expect either the `producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction()` or `producer.commitTransaction()` to throw an exception. I do get an error if the producer in ConsumerB uses the same `transactionId`, however, but that's not a solution IMHO.

Comment: I do not get an exception from the consumers regardless if the transactionID is the same or different. My oldest applications producer does however throw an exception(sometimes) if the transactionID already exist. This exception is thrown once and then everything works, but if I call the same functionality, then it works. I think this exception is might be unrelated.

Comment: I have reported the bug to Apache Kafka. I am very eager to figure out if this is a bug.

Comment: I think the reason why it appears to work with the same transactionID. Consumer B is also my producer - This application is launched first. When I send a record, then I get an exception. If I try to send a second record then I do not get an exception. I think Kafka is assigning the Consumer B a new transaction ID. This seems like a flaw for me.